# Ruby: how to intercept method, fiddle with the args and then call the method

Tags: ruby, activerecord, patch

I require different behavior from ActiveRecord::AttributeAssignment.assign_attributes(new_attributes, options).

For my entire web application, I want to evaluate [and frequently overwrite] new_attributes.  (I want to do this to support third party UI widgets which do not follow rails form naming conventions).  Although this might be a bit stinky, I can write the patch to only activate if the call did come from the third party form.

I have written a patch and can override the normal behavior; however, I'm wondering if it is possible to call the original method from within my patch?

Of course I can just cut and paste the original assign_attributes into my patch.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`alias_method_chain`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/Module/alias_method_chain) exists for this exact situation.

It's not always the right choice, but works well when you have a fitting use case, which this one looks to be.

Comment: Turns out that I was barking up the wrong tree.  But this was the right answer for that tree.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

alias or alias_method should do the trick, see
[Ruby at about.com: aliasing](http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyfeatures/a/aliasing.htm)